# Designing a public API for a JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, modules

I am writing a module that can access `localStorage` through a public API which exposes methods that allow string or array returns.

It doesn't feel as though I'm doing this in the most effective way. For example, I feel as though using:

`var tudCache = getTud();` to grab the object from `getTud()` doesn't feel like the most correct implementation.

I'm inclined to use an `if` statement i.e. `if(getTud().isSuccessful)` to check the conditional but then I would have to re-execute `getTud().result` to return the result inside that conditional, causing the `getTud()` function to be called twice.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
_self.getTudCache = function () {

    // returns an object. {'isSuccessful': boolean, 'result': String}
    function getTud() {

        return localstorage.getItem(tudStorageKey);

    }

    function getString() {

        var tudCache = getTud();

        if (tudCache.isSuccessful)
            return tudCache.result;
        return "";

    }

    function getArr() {

        var tudCache = getTud();

        if (tudCache.isSuccessful)
            return JSON.parse(tudCache.result)[tudCacheKey];
        return [];
    }

     return {
         getString: getString,
         getArr: getArr
     }
};
```

Comment: I'm not even sure this code works. `localStorage.getItem` return strings, not objects. Can you add in the rest of the code, as well as a simple demo?

Comment: I should have clarified that we're using a wrapper for ```localStorage```. See this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/y7eS0R22g0dRkbG4U3US?p=catalogue

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that it'd be simpler to always use JSON, rather than limit yourself to strings and arrays, specifically.

E.g.

```
function retrieve(key) {
  var json = localStorage.getItem(key);
  try {
    return JSON.parse(json).value;
  } catch(e) {
    return json; // either null or a non-comforming value
  }
}

function store(key, value) {
  var json = JSON.stringify({ value: value });
  localStorage.setItem(key, json);
}
```

This will let you store and retrieve any JSON-serializable value including strings and arrays. You can wrap/namespace it however you like.